# Parsing JSON with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I suspect this is a fairly basic concept, but two days of trial and error, google searches, and random keyboard mashing have worn me down.  I'm attempting to parse JSON returned from a URL, but I'm running into an issue that I suspect is related to the array inside the JSON.

What am I doing wrong?

JSON:

```
{
"HotelInformationResponse": {
    "@hotelId": "106347",
    "customerSessionId": "0ABAA83F-4430-B291-3432-E0A2DC790CA0",
    "HotelImages": {
        "@size": "16",
        "HotelImage": [
            {
                "hotelImageId": 4694179,
                "name": "",
                "category": 1,
                "type": 0,
                "caption": "Exterior",
                "url": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_44_b.jpg",
                "thumbnailUrl": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_44_t.jpg",
                "supplierId": 13,
                "width": 350,
                "height": 350,
                "byteSize": 0
            },
            {
                "hotelImageId": 4694182,
                "name": "",
                "category": 2,
                "type": 0,
                "caption": "Lobby",
                "url": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_47_b.jpg",
                "thumbnailUrl": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_47_t.jpg",
                "supplierId": 13,
                "width": 350,
                "height": 350,
                "byteSize": 0
            },
            {
                "hotelImageId": 4694171,
                "name": "",
                "category": 2,
                "type": 0,
                "caption": "Lobby",
                "url": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_36_b.jpg",
                "thumbnailUrl": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_36_t.jpg",
                "supplierId": 13,
                "width": 350,
                "height": 350,
                "byteSize": 0
            },
            {
                "hotelImageId": 4694174,
                "name": "",
                "category": 2,
                "type": 0,
                "caption": "Lobby",
                "url": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_39_b.jpg",
                "thumbnailUrl": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_39_t.jpg",
                "supplierId": 13,
                "width": 350,
                "height": 350,
                "byteSize": 0
            },
            {
                "hotelImageId": 4694168,
                "name": "",
                "category": 3,
                "type": 0,
                "caption": "Guest Room",
                "url": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_33_b.jpg",
                "thumbnailUrl": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_33_t.jpg",
                "supplierId": 13,
                "width": 350,
                "height": 350,
                "byteSize": 0
            },
            {
                "hotelImageId": 4694173,
                "name": "",
                "category": 3,
                "type": 0,
                "caption": "Guest Room",
                "url": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_38_b.jpg",
                "thumbnailUrl": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_38_t.jpg",
                "supplierId": 13,
                "width": 350,
                "height": 350,
                "byteSize": 0
            },
            {
                "hotelImageId": 4694177,
                "name": "",
                "category": 3,
                "type": 0,
                "caption": "Guest Room",
                "url": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_42_b.jpg",
                "thumbnailUrl": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_42_t.jpg",
                "supplierId": 13,
                "width": 350,
                "height": 350,
                "byteSize": 0
            },
            {
                "hotelImageId": 4694165,
                "name": "",
                "category": 10,
                "type": 0,
                "caption": "Restaurant",
                "url": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_30_b.jpg",
                "thumbnailUrl": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_30_t.jpg",
                "supplierId": 13,
                "width": 350,
                "height": 350,
                "byteSize": 0
            },
            {
                "hotelImageId": 4694166,
                "name": "",
                "category": 10,
                "type": 0,
                "caption": "Restaurant",
                "url": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_31_b.jpg",
                "thumbnailUrl": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_31_t.jpg",
                "supplierId": 13,
                "width": 350,
                "height": 350,
                "byteSize": 0
            },
            {
                "hotelImageId": 6601500,
                "name": "",
                "category": 11,
                "type": 0,
                "caption": "Interior",
                "url": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_56_b.jpg",
                "thumbnailUrl": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_56_t.jpg",
                "supplierId": 13,
                "width": 350,
                "height": 350,
                "byteSize": 0
            },
            {
                "hotelImageId": 4694176,
                "name": "",
                "category": 12,
                "type": 0,
                "caption": "Pool",
                "url": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_41_b.jpg",
                "thumbnailUrl": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_41_t.jpg",
                "supplierId": 13,
                "width": 350,
                "height": 350,
                "byteSize": 0
            },
            {
                "hotelImageId": 4694170,
                "name": "",
                "category": 12,
                "type": 0,
                "caption": "Pool",
                "url": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_35_b.jpg",
                "thumbnailUrl": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_35_t.jpg",
                "supplierId": 13,
                "width": 350,
                "height": 350,
                "byteSize": 0
            },
            {
                "hotelImageId": 4694172,
                "name": "",
                "category": 12,
                "type": 0,
                "caption": "Pool",
                "url": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_37_b.jpg",
                "thumbnailUrl": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_37_t.jpg",
                "supplierId": 13,
                "width": 350,
                "height": 350,
                "byteSize": 0
            },
            {
                "hotelImageId": 4694180,
                "name": "",
                "category": 21,
                "type": 0,
                "caption": "Lounge/Bar",
                "url": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_45_b.jpg",
                "thumbnailUrl": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_45_t.jpg",
                "supplierId": 13,
                "width": 350,
                "height": 350,
                "byteSize": 0
            },
            {
                "hotelImageId": 4694181,
                "name": "",
                "category": 21,
                "type": 0,
                "caption": "Lounge/Bar",
                "url": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_46_b.jpg",
                "thumbnailUrl": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_46_t.jpg",
                "supplierId": 13,
                "width": 350,
                "height": 350,
                "byteSize": 0
            },
            {
                "hotelImageId": 4694175,
                "name": "",
                "category": 38,
                "type": 0,
                "caption": "Suite",
                "url": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_40_b.jpg",
                "thumbnailUrl": "http://images.travelnow.com/hotels/1000000/10000/5900/5900/5900_40_t.jpg",
                "supplierId": 13,
                "width": 350,
                "height": 350,
                "byteSize": 0
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

My simplified code:

```
api = Expedia::Api.new
response = api.get_information({:hotelId => '106347'}) 
data = response.body
parsed = JSON.parse(data.to_json)

thumbnail = parsed['HotelInformationResponse']['HotelImages']['HotelImage']['thumbNailUrl']
```

This returns an error "no implicit conversion of String into Integer" at the thumbnail line.  I understand that the JSON lists more then one 'thumbNailUrl', and I need to specify with I'm requesting, but I'm not sure how.  I would just like to retrieve the first 'thumbNailUrl'.

Incidentally, the EAN API gem I'm using is located here: https://github.com/zaidakram/expedia

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line `parsed['HotelInformationResponse']['HotelImages']` gives you an `Array` of `Hash`. So you need to access each `Hash` inside the array by index(s). Thus you need to go as below :-

```
parsed['HotelInformationResponse']['HotelImages']['HotelImage'][0]['thumbnailUrl']
```

If you want to get all *thumbnails* then, iterate over it as

```
thumbnails = parsed['HotelInformationResponse']['HotelImages']['HotelImage'].map do |hash|
   hash[thumbnailUrl]
end
```

Comment: I suspected that, and I've tried that, but then <%= thumbnail %> returns nothing, it's just blank.

Comment: @user3799686 Because, `thumbnailUrl` is the actual *key* not the *thumbNailUrl*, which you have used.

Answer (score 0):

To get the first hotel image you can do:

```
thumbnail = parsed['HotelInformationResponse']['HotelImages']['HotelImage'][0]['thumbNailUrl']
```

If you wanted to get all the thumbnails you can do something like:

```
thumbnails = []

parsed['HotelInformationResponse']['HotelImages']['HotelImage'].each { |thumbnail| thumbnails << thumbnail['thumNailUrl'] }
```

Comment: I suspected that, and I've tried that, but then `<%= thumbnail %>` returns nothing, it's just blank.